# How to initiate an action after 3 mouse clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, jquery-events

I am new to writing code but I'm trying to figure out to have a div disappear after being clicked three times.  I know how to get it to disappear after one or two clicks but I'm not sure how to do it after three.  I wrote a while loop that should iterate up once after each click but instead the function doesn't wait for the div to be clicked and goes ahead and fades out the div.

```
var threeClick = function() {
    var n = 0;
    while(n > 2) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('div').click(function(){
                n++;
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('div').fadeOut('slow');
        });
    }
}
threeClick();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var n
$(document).ready(function()
{
    n=0;
    $('div').click(function()
    {
        n++;
        if(n==3)
        {
            n=0;
            $('div').fadeOut('slow');
        }   
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I like how your's simple and clean.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var n = 0;
    $('div').click(function() {
        n++;

        if(n == 3) {
           $('div').fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

I'm wondering why your `while` loop doesn't block execution while it sits and spins. JavaScript is not multi-threaded; there is a single thread of execution and I would imagine that the `while` would block that thread. But aside from that it won't really work because you're never checking the value of `n` before you fade out the div. This is why the fade-out happens almost immediately. There is also no need for numerous `$(document).ready(...)` calls; one will do.

I would also recommend using [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var n = 0;
    $('div').on('click', function() {
        n++;

        if(n >= 3) {
           $('div').fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

This works because the `n` which has been defined in the anonymous function (passed to `.ready`) is available to the callback (closure) passed to `.on` or `.click`. Closures are lexically bound to the scope in which they are defined, which means that anything defined in the enclosed scope is available to the closure. So your `n`'s value will be updated and available to the closure.

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks for filling in the details, it really helped me understand how it all works together.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var n = 0;
    $('div').click(function() {
        n++;
        if (n == 3) {
            $(this).fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ugfUF/)

You don't have to repeat `$(document).ready`. This is a method (from jQuery) called when DOM is ready. So your code should go in this function;

Comment: Learn something new everyday. I've only done simple things on codeacademy and never came across where it talks about using '$(document.ready)'. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this too

```
$(function(){
    $('#myDiv').on('click', function(){
        var clicks = $(this).data('clicks') || 0;
        $(this).data('clicks', clicks+1);
        if($(this).data('clicks') >=3 ) $(this).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vaj3U/1/)

Comment: Thanks for showing another variation.  Your's looks very compact but I think I understand it.

Comment: You are Welcome and yes, since we can use `jQuery` then why not utilize it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the variable holding the count outside of the function or it will reset each time the function is called. Give the div a class name - here i have used 'divClassName'.

```
var numClicks = 0;

$(function() {

    $(document).on("click",".divClassName",function() {

        numClicks+=1;

        if (numClicks > 2) {

            $('div').fadeOut('slow');

        }   
    }

};
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about keeping the count outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you could do something like that

```
var counter=0;
$('div').on('click',function(){
           counter++; 
           if(counter==3)$('div').fadeOut();}
         );
```